# Javascript that equal this when referencing function to variable

Tags: javascript, oop, this

Yes, this is another question about storing `this` in a variable (`that`), but I'm confused about this:

```
function Constructor(){
    this.key = 'my key'
};


Constructor.prototype.start = function(){
    var that = this;
    return (function (){
        console.log(that.key)
    }());

};

foo = new Constructor;
foo.start()

bar = new Constructor;
newFoo = bar.start
newFoo()
```

I thought since `this` is stored as a variable I can pass around the `start()` method without loosing the scope?
I know this has been discussed quite often but I cannot find an answer which fits in this specific situation.

How will it be possible to get back the scope in `newFoo()` without using `Constructor.apply(this)` ?

Thank you

Comment: It won't, you have to either change the way the function work, or pass the proper scope with `newFoo.apply(bar)`

Comment: Could you provide an example of what your expected output is?  T.J.'s answer is correct, if that's the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: [var newFoo = bar.start.bind(bar)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Please Show me why You downvoted This? That is a reasonable question, so whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought since this is stored as a variable I can pass around the start() method without loosing the scope?

No, because you're still using the value of `this` as it is when `start` is called, just indirectly. You could do this **inside** `Constructor`:

```
function Constructor() {
    // ...other stuff...

    var that = this;
    this.start = function(){
         console.log(that.key)
    };

    // ...other stuff...
}
```

*(...and remove the one you're putting on the prototype).*

Now you can pass around `start` all you want; `that` will be the value `this` had when the constructor was called. `start` has an *enduring reference* to the `that` variable from the call to the constructor.

The cost, of course, is that every instance created via `Constructor` has its *own* copy of the `start` function. Most modern JavaScript engines will be smart enough to reuse the code of the function (but they're required to create separate function instances for each `start`, it's just the actual code behind the scenes they can reuse).

Your other option is not to handle this within `Constructor` or `start`, but to handle it if/when you give copies of `start` out elsewhere, using `Function#bind`. `Function#bind` is an ECMAScript5 (ES5) feature, but it can be shimmed on older engines.

Example:

```
// Nice boring constructor with `start` on the prototype
// Note I've made the key an argument; in your code, all of them had the same key
function Constructor(key) {
    this.key = key;
}
Constructor.prototype.start = function() {
    console.log(this.key);
};

// **********

// Using it
var c1 = new Constructor("c1");

// Use it normally
c1.start();                       // "c1" as you'd expect

// Use it forgetting that `this` will change
setTimeout(c1.start, 0);          // "undefined" - doh!

// Use it via Function#bind
setTimeout(c1.start.bind(c1), 0); // "c1"
```

More *(on my blog)*:

- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: Thank You, but  is there also a way to achieve this in  start() method or do I really Need to use the constructor for this? If so thats no Problem, its just for testing

Comment: @ChristophHa: If you put `start` on the prototype, you can't save the value of `this` in `that` because you don't have access to that value at that point in time. The reason it works within `Constructor` is that at that point, you have access to the value you want `that` to have. Your other option, of course, is to use `Function#bind` if/when you hand out `start`, I'll add that.

Comment: Ah yes, did not see this yet, really good explanation, looking Forward to your blog:)